# Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of modelName out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I trying to read this json value and convert it to java object

```
{"message":"1"}
```

which is returned from this string.

```
http://mywebservice:8080/SpringService/service/updatepool/selectdynamicurl/~!~''WEB1500001''~!~
```

but i always get this error

> Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of
>   org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.CheckOpjID[] out of
>   START_OBJECT token

Here is my CHeckOPJID.java class

```
public class CheckOpjID {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

and here is my controller class

```
String url = "http://mywebservice:8080/SpringService/service/updatepool/selectdynamicurl/~!~''WEB1500001''~!~";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
CheckOpjID[] messageArray = restTemplate.getForObject(url, CheckOpjID[].class);
```

which is i have same code, and it worked! then i trying to create new class in another controller, then it starting give me Could not read JSON error, until this line (below)

```
CheckOpjID[] messageArray = restTemplate.getForObject(url, CheckOpjID[].class);
```

what i missed here??

Comment: in the `RestTemplate` you are expecting json array, but you are receiving json object and jackson http message converter cannot parse json object into json array. if it change this line : `CheckOpjID message = restTemplate.getForObject(url, CheckOpjID.class);` may be it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i missed, i have to delete the array Object, as Nikolay Rusev suggested

> CheckOpjID messageArray = restTemplate.getForObject(url,
>   CheckOpjID.class);